# Laravel, Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server [2]

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel, sql-server-2012

I'm new to Laravel framework, trying hard to check for database configuration.

Changed the host,database,username and password fields in the following files in 'sqlsrv' array

> ```
> app/config/database.php
> app/config/local/database.php
> ```

After enabling debug to true, ended up with the following error:

```
PDOException (08001)
SQLSTATE[08001]: [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server [2]
```

Enabled the Named Pipes, TCP/IP from  SQL Server Configuration Manager.

Is there anyway so that I can trace the exact problem in the database connection? Stuck finding a way to connect to sql server 2012 database with Laravel framework.

Comment: Is your server open for remote connection?  http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/05/21/sql-server-fix-error-provider-named-pipes-provider-error-40-could-not-open-a-connection-to-sql-server-microsoft-sql-server-error/

Comment: configured those remote connection previously but no use, running on xampp local host , unable to connect to sql server with laravel but it is connecting normally with sqlsrv methods but not with pdo in laravel